# Test not found in .NET Test Explorer Extension for VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

I can not see my tests in .NET Test Explorer Extension.
I've already configured settings.json

```json
{
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "**/*ComprasPrevidencia/ComprasPrevidencia.csproj",
    "dotnet-test-explorer.autoWatch": true,
    "dotnet-test-explorer.runInParallel": true 
}
```

At terminal I search for avaible tests with success:

```
dotnet test -t -v=q
```

> Os Testes a seguir estão disponíveis:
> Acumulacao
> AcumulacaoRisco
> Risco

My .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0"/>
     <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0"/>
     <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="85.0.4183.8700"/>
     <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML_Excel" Version="1.0.0"/>
     <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.95.3"/>
     <PackageReference Include="SQL" Version="1.0.5075.31045"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image: The VSCode]

Comment: Just to confirm, the setting.json file you've opened is your user setting (not the global setting), right? That is, it is present in your work folder insider the `.vscode` folder, right?

Comment: Also, please update your question to include the folder path of your workspace folder, and where the test project is located.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a similar topic. It appears to be resolved in the following way.

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73554226/13548895)

workaround: change the tree view to "flat"

update settings.json with `"dotnet-test-explorer.treeMode": "flat"`

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the property `"dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath"` expects the relative path of the parent folder of the required `csproj` file. This has always worked for me. The extension scans the folder for all `csproj` files within the matched path and finds the required project(s) that contain unit tests.

So, if your working directory looks like this

```
.
├── MyCoreLib
│   ├── MyCoreLib.csproj
│   └── Lib.cs
├── SomeOtherProj
│   ├── SomeOtherProj.csproj
│   └── OtherProjFile.cs
└── MyTestLib
    ├── MyTestLib.csproj
    └── UnitTests.cs
```

Here, the path of the parent folder of the test project is `MyTestLib/`, so the user setting file (contained within `.vscode/setting.json`) should contain

```json
{
    "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "MyTestLib/" 
    // Relative path of parent folder only
}
```

And with that, the extension should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the problem + solution.

In class

```
Acme/Test/AcmeTests.cs
```

There was a reference to a class

```
Acme/Acme.cs
```

but no corresponding

using Acme;

Also

```
Acme/Acme.Tests.csproj
```

Needed

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Acme\Acme.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I think VS Code was not complaining about this, because these 2 `.csproj` files were not part of `.sln`

Regardless, ALL tests were not being found because of this one broken test config. Once fixed, VS Code was able to find all the tests.