# VS Code - Test Explorer no longer showing any tests. Error: "Cannot read properties of null"

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

**What's Not working**

At some point, the lists of tests that used to show up in Test Explorer are now no longer appearing. When I try to refresh the list, I get an error that the system is encountering a null value somewhere.

I have the following setup:

**VSCODE**

```
Version: 1.70.2 (user setup)
Commit: e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662
Date: 2022-08-16T05:35:13.448Z
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

**Widget Solution Setup:**

I have a main project, and a test project organized like this:

[image]

**Widgets.Server Project file:**

In part, this is what the project file contains - NB:  the platform

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
```

This is what the Test project file contains - matching platform:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TagLibSharp" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Shouldly" Version="4.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Widgets.Server\Widgets.Server.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**settings.json**

In my .vscode folder which lives at the same level as the server folder, this is what the settings file contains: (which is correct as far as path to the test project)

```
{
  "dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "Widgets.Server.Tests/Widgets.Server.Tests.csproj"
}
```

**Cannot Read Properties Error**
[image]

**Manually Running Tests**

When I open up a specific test class, and run it, it seems to work.  Please see the picture below:
[image]

**EDIT 1**

The other behavior I'm noticing is that when I first open VSCOde, it finds all the tests and lists the total at the bottom status bar.  But sometimes, when I try to debug just one test, I get this error:

```
Failed to start debugger: "System.InvalidOperationException: The debugger could not be started\r\n   at OmniSharp.DotNetTest.Services.DebugTestService.Handle(DebugTestGetStartInfoRequest request) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\OmniSharp.DotNetTest\\Services\\DebugTestService.cs:line 42\r\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.GetFirstNotEmptyResponseFromHandlers(ExportHandler`2[] handlers, TRequest request) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\OmniSharp.Host\\Endpoint\\EndpointHandler.cs:line 198\r\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.HandleRequestForLanguage(String language, TRequest request, RequestPacket packet) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\OmniSharp.Host\\Endpoint\\EndpointHandler.cs:line 234\r\n   at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2.Process(RequestPacket packet, LanguageModel model, JToken requestObject) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\OmniSharp.Host\\Endpoint\\EndpointHandler.cs:line 143\r\n   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host.HandleRequest(String json, ILogger logger) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\OmniSharp.Stdio\\Host.cs:line 258"
```

And in the output window i see this:

```
----- Debugging test method Widgets.Server.Tests.FeatureToggleSampleControllerShould.Return_String_If_Toggle_Enabled -----

MSBuild version 17.3.0+92e077650 for .NET

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4809,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.objectmodel\17.1.0\lib\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll" to "bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll". The process cannot access the file 'c:\Users\me\Documents\src\codeReview\widgets\server\Widgets.Server.Tests\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll' because it is being used by another process. [c:\Users\me\Documents\src\codeReview\widgets\server\Widgets.Server.Tests\Jw.O3M.Server.Tests.csproj]
    10 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

When this happens, I have to delete the bin folder in the Test project and also find and kill the testhost process.
And then I can run a single test by clicking on the "Run Test | Debug Test" options under the [Fact] decorator

But the test explorer remains empty.
No matter what I do i cannot get the list of tests to appear.

Comment: This happened to me as well. Running tests from inside the test files still works but the test explorer couldn't find any of the tests. Everytime you try to refresh the test explorer it shows the same error popup on the lower-right displaying "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'command')"

Tried reinstalling the .net test explorer extension but it didn't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a know issue in the Test Explorer extension, see https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer/issues/370

A workaround is to show the tests in a 'flat' Tree Mode view:
[image: Screenshot of settings in VSCode]

Comment: sorry i thought I had searched for bugs related to this but i missed this post.  Thanks man!

Comment: Settings > Extensions > .NET Core Test Explorer > Tree mode. Set to flat. Or in settings.json, "dotnet-test-explorer.treeMode": "flat".

Comment: It worked. i set the flat then restart vs code. After that changed to merge again and works perfectly

Comment: The workaround didn't work for me.